# Redshift to_date issue: Invalid date format; Specified day twice

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert a string to date in Redshift.

```
select to_date('Fri Apr 03 00:00:07 2020','Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss YYYY')
```

I am getting an issue `Invalid operation: Invalid date format: Specified day twice`.

Is it not possible to mention both Day name and Day of month as a number in the same date string?

I am following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html) reference for date formats in Redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are specifying the date twice in your format string - day of week and day of month.  Which is Redshift to use if they are in conflict?  The reference you provided is general in nature, specifying both input and output format patterns (converting to a string you may want both date and day of week).  If you just want to ignore the day of the week in the input string just use the format string 'XXX Mon DD hh24:mi:ss YYYY'.